# What does std(A, 0, 3) mean?

Tags: matlab, matrix, std, standard-deviation

I am running the following code in which I am generating ten 4 x 4 matrix with random values.

```
A = zeros(4,4,10);
for idx = 1:size(A,3)
   A(:,:,idx) = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 0 0 0 1].*randn(4,4)
end

X = std(A, 0, 3)
```

`X = std(A, 0, 1)` gives the standard deviation of each column and
`X = std(A, 0, 2)` gives the standard deviation of each row.

What does `X = std(A, 0, 3)` give?

I am getting a 4x4 matrix value answer as follows

```
4.0479    2.7137    1.8706    1.2579
4.9812    9.0766    7.2079    4.1866
1.0548    2.7205    3.3140    3.8712
     0         0         0    0.8496
```

Comment: It compute the standard deviation along the third dimension of the matrix `tformStd`.

Comment: Was there anything wrong with the explanation you found in the [MATLAB help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html)?

Comment: I got the answer from @obchardon. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `X = std(A, 0, 3)` is the standard deviation **across the third dimension**.

The **0** argument is the degrees of freedom for the bias normalization. In this case the denominator is **N-1**

If you use **1**, it’s going to be **N**

---

**From the documentation:**

w — Weight
0 (default) | 1 | vector
Weight, specified as one of these values:

0 — Normalize by N-1, where N is the number of observations. If there is only one observation, then the weight is 1.
1 — Normalize by N.
Vector made up of nonnegative scalar weights corresponding to the dimension of A along which the standard deviation is calculated.